# Designing layout in html

Tags: html

I use CSS to stylize my pages. I use % style instead of using px values. However, since I need to add several elements of different sizes in different positions, I end up spending more time in designing the layout than the coding.

I tried using a WYSIWYG editor but it uses px style coding. Can someone help me with a solution so that I can design the layout quickly and proceed to real part? I use WordPad right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is practice more.  Get better at coding them, and reuse parts from prior projects where it makes sense.

There is no WYSIWYG tool that will save you time, for most projects.  They all write garbage code, because editing with such a tool is a bit ambiguous.  It is up to you as a web developer to write your markup and styles in a way that will be interpreted correctly across many user agents.

Comment: I just need to place my divs properly. inside my div I am very comfortable

Comment: i am trying microsoft publisher now and still the same :/ it uses in format

Comment: @gordon, Please re-read my answer to you.  Your solution is to code them yourself.  Microsoft Publisher especially does a bad job at creating HTML.

Comment: am i doing too much. should i just use the pixel values instead of going for percentage?

Comment: @gordon, No!  You should use what is needed to present your content in the most usable, readable, and compatible way possible.  Often that is percentages.  Sometimes that is just hard-coded values.  It depends on your needs.

Comment: currntly i am just doing trial and error to get the elements in the place :3 if i get it properly done i will publish it to my website and add the link in my profile. thanks anyways

Comment: i have seen in tumblr u have html code on left part of page and when u edit it automatically the webpage preview is displayed on right. i wanted something like that except that it was offfline

Comment: so i work like edit the css in wordpad, save it. and open the html in browser > take 2 clicks and window minimizing which brings discontinuity and my head flips because of that :/

Comment: @gordon, For CSS, you can use your browser's development tools and modify it and see the changes immediately.  Your changes aren't saved to disk, but you can copy and paste them as you go.  With enough practice, you won't need so much trial-and-error.

Comment: I have done enough practice and feel quite comfortable now, thanks.

Comment: Theres just one last thing now. I wanted whole page to have water ripple like effect and downloaded that ripple script by the guy who made it for container element but I can't change it to work for whole background. any idea?

Comment: @gordon, Hard to say without seeing any code... post that as a new/separate question.